# Swift - contentsOfURL returns 'nil' with specific site, but it works on browser

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, initwithcontentsofurl

This code works with other URL's, but not with this one. It always returns nil with "contentsOfURL". Why?

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.bsnpr.com/api/standing.asp?serie=1&liga=1&y=2015")
var err: NSError?
var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: nil, error: &err)
```

"err" delivers the message:

> "Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x7f8f32c2e1e0 {NSURL=http://www.bsnpr.com/api/standing.asp?serie=1&liga=1&y=2015})"

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See that `error` parameter?  Instead of supplying `nil`, supply an instance on `NSError` -  If you do this you will get error 256, which unfortunately isn't very helpful; it basically means something went wrong.  It seems that `contentsOfURL` doesn't like your server for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Your server delivers data with `Transfer-Encoding` set to `chunked`, and `NSData` doesn't like it.

You can get your data with a REST framework like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.bsnpr.com/api/standing.asp?serie=1&liga=1&y=2015")
    .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        println(json) // works with your url, I just tested
}
```